# Using cout to output type int from cin.get()

Tags: c++, cin, cout

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c;
    cout<<cin.eof()<<endl;

    while((c=cin.get())!=EOF)
    {
        cout<<c<<endl;
    }

    cout<<cin.eof()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code is shown above.
Here is the output.

[image]

I know that I ought to use cout.put() to output the result.
But 
my question is where does the "10" come from?

my ide is dev-c++ 5.11

Comment: Don't take screenshots of output windows if your question is not about colours and font of the console window or about strange characters that cannot be easily copied and pasted (you get the idea). Post text. This is not Instagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 is a linefeed in ASCII code. It came from pressing enter after typing in the input.

Comment: Then if i use cout.put(c);  , there would be no another linefeed.Why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but perhaps some information may help. `put` takes `c`, an `int`, as a `char` and writes it as a character resulting in a linefeed being printed rather than the numeric encoding of a linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the 10 is the character '\n' which is a line feed, its decimal value is 10, when using `cin.get()` you will read a line feed character along with the inserted ones because of the enter key, now if updating your code as bellow 10 is no longer printed:

```
while (c != EOF )
{
    c = cin.get();

    if (c != '\n')
    {
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}
```